# Multiples of 67 in a constructed array of arrays?

Tags: code-golf, math

A triangle-shaped table is constructed such the first row is "1, 3, 5, 7, ..., 99"

Each subsequent row has the following properties:

- One less element than the row above
- Each element is the sum of the two elements above it

Like so:

```
1   3   5    7    9    11 ....
  4   8   12   16   20 ....
    ...............
```

This continues until the last row with one element.

How many elements are divisible by 67?

Fewest lines, chars, or whatever may win.  Depends on ingenuity.

EDIT: the answer is 17 but you have to prove it.

ADDENDUM:
I have three-line python code for this but try to beat it:

```
a = [[2*i+1 for i in range(50)]]
while len(a[-1])>1:a.append([a[-1][i]+a[-1][i+1] for i in range(len(a[-1])-1)])
print len([i for b in a for i in b if i%67==0])
```

Comment: Heads up: the numbers overflow 32-bit `int`.  You'll need big integers (or at least 64-bit integers) for the final rows.

Comment: Is this the way to go? Inform the others of possible pitfalls? I would prefer to wait for the first users, trapping into the trap.

Comment: By induction, row (2n) = 4^n (2n+1, 2n+3, ..., 99-2n); and row (2n+1) = 4^(n+1) (n+1, n+2, ..., 49-n). gcd(4, 67) = 1, 49 < 67 < 99 < 2*67, so there is one number divisible by 67 in the even rows until row 32 (=99-67), for a total of 17. If I put this in a comment then I can justify hard-coding the answer, and when I golf I remove comments. Therefore I've downvoted this as a bad question.

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  Sounds good.  Now all you have to do is code-golf the proof ;)

Comment: @Peter Taylor: I dare you to write the proof in [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### JavaScript: <strike>91, 88</strike> (thanks trinithis), <strike>84, 77</strike> (thanks again trinithis), <strike>75</strike> (thanks shesek), 74 Characters (thanks Shmiddty)

**91-->88** - See Trinithis's comment
**88-->84** - moved `j--` into conditional check.
**84-->77** - See trinithis's comment (removed `{}` from for loops, ignored first index of `a` array) plus some additional work (fixed logic for building arrays and incrementing counters)
**77-->75** - See Shesek's comment (instead of `(condition)&&val++`: `val+=(condition)`)
**75-->74** - See Shmiddty's comment (instead of `i=c=1,a=[]`: `a=[i=c=1]`)

Golfed:

```
for(a=[i=c=1];i<51;)for(a[i]=i*2-1,j=i++;j>1;)c+=1>(a[--j]=a[1+j]+a[j])%67
```

Ungolfed:

```
/**
 * i - counter for array index and array initialization
 * c - count of elements divisible by 67
 * a - array of numbers in diagonal bottom-to-right row. 
 *        For example, here are the first 3 iterations:  [1], [4,3], [12,8,5]
 * j - index into array a
 */
for(a=[i=c=1];i<51;){
    a[i]=i*2-1;
    for(j=i++;j>1;){
        c+=1>(a[--j]=a[1+j]+a[j])%67
    }
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/zSNKa/) for both as well as a test that outputs what is in the arrays for the first 3 iterations.

Note:  I initialize the count to 1 because the first row [1,3,5..67..97,99] has one number divisible by 67.  That way, I did not have to worry about checking the first row.

Comment: `if(0==(a[j]=a[j]+a[j+1])%67)c++` -> `1>(a[j]=a[j]+a[j+1])%67&&c++` Might be able to use `!` instead of `0==` or `1>` if you can figure it out.

Comment: 73 chars: `for(i=c=1,a=[];i<51;)for(a[i]=i*2-1,j=i++;j;)1>(a[--j]=a[j]+a[j])%67&&c++`

Comment: @trinithis: Thanks!  One thing:  I didn't understand `a[--j]=a[j]+a[j]` in your code.  Because of this, I did some debugging and ended up finding a mistake with my second iteration (`a[j]=a[j--]+a[j]` is not equal to `a[j-1]=a[j]+a[j-1]` but instead `a[j]=a[j]+a[j-1]`).  This is fixed in the above version, and is much shorter because of you, so thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sliced down 2 more characters by adding the boolean result of `1>...` to c (which is casted to an integer), `for(i=c=1,a=[];i<51;)for(a[i]=i*2-1,j=i++;j>1;)c+=1>(a[--j]=a[1+j]+a[j])%67`

Comment: @shesek: Updated, thanks much!

Comment: `a=[i=c=1];` saves another character

Comment: @Shmiddty:  Thanks much, code-ninja:  Updated!

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell - 86 chars

**98 → 92**: Use list comprehensions and `sum` instead of `filter` and `length`.

**92 → 86**: Convert nested list comprehensions into one, and change `==0` to `<1` (thanks st0le).

```
f s=zipWith(+)s$tail s
main=print$sum[1|r<-take 50$iterate f[1,3..99],n<-r,n`mod`67<1]
```

Ungolfed:

```
initialRow :: [Integer]
initialRow = [1,3..99]

nextRow :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
nextRow xs = zipWith (+) xs (tail xs)

triangle :: [[Integer]]
triangle = takeWhile (not . null) $ iterate nextRow initialRow

main = print $ length $ filter ((== 0) . (`mod` 67)) $ concat triangle
```

Comment: replace `==0` by `<1`

Comment: You can replace `f` with `tail>>=zipWith(+)`

Comment: You can also change the inners of the comprehention to `n<-(take50$iterate f[1,3..99])>>=id, `

Comment: Nice trick with using `sum`

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica 82 chars

```
Count[Mod[#,67]==0&/@Flatten@NestList[2MovingAverage[#,2]&,Range[1,99,2],49],True]

-> 17
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 95 bytes

```
l,c=range(1,100,2),0
while l:c+=len([i for i in l if i%67<1]);l=map(sum,zip(l,l[1:]))
print c
```

Comment: Nice one.  I borrowed some of your ideas, and found a few places to save a few characters.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 48

```
1225-~+/,-.*67|((<:/|.)a)*(+1&|.)^:a>:2*a=:i.50x
```

Explanation (bits of it, anyway):

- a is 0 .. 49
- `>:2*a` is `1 3 5 ...`
- The verb `(+1&|.)` shifts a row and adds it to the original to get the desired next row (plus extras, since the result is still 50 elements).
- `(+1&|.)^:a>:2*a` gives 50 rows of results. Row one is `1 3 5` etc, row 2 is `4 8 12` etc.
- `((<:/|.)a)` is a 50x50 matrix of 1 1 ... 1 1, 1 1 ... 1 0 etc. down to 1 0 ... 0 0. This zeroes out the 1225 extras. (1225 is the 49th triangular number.)
- After taking mod 67 and counting, we subtract those 1225 zeroes that we know will be present.

Answer (score 3):

### Python

85 bytes - thanks to st0le

```
l,c=range(1,100,2),0
while l:c+=sum(i%67<1for i in l);l=map(sum,zip(l,l[1:]))
print c
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ <strike>133</strike> <strike>131</strike> 125 chars, 2 Lines

```
#include<iostream>
__int64 c=1,s=1,r,a=2,e=51,i;int main(){for(;e;c=s+=s+a,a*=2)for(i=e--;--i;c+=a)c%67?0:r++;std::cout<<r;}
```

I'm not sure how portable this is with the use of `__int64`, if it does complains you     can change it to `long long`.

### Ungolfed

```
#include<iostream>

__int64 curr,start=1,ret,add=2,end_line=50;
int main(){
    for(;end_line>0;end_line--,add*=2){
        curr=start;
        for(int i=1;i<=end_line;++i){
            if(curr%67){
            }else{
                ret++;
            }
            curr+=add;
        }
        start+=start+add;
    }
    std::cout<<ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `=1` in `c=1` in the golfed version?

Comment: You were right thanks, well spotted.

Comment: The `i` loop can be shortened by counting down. `for(i=e;i--;c+=a)` (i think)

Comment: @st0le, Thanks, rejigged it a bit as well though I'm now unsure about that `c=1`.  I get the correct result without it but looking through the debug I don't think it is doing it the correct way, anyway i put it back in.

Comment: Can't you just use `int` if you change the `%67` to `%=67`?

Comment: @Peter Taylor, it's not just `curr` that goes over the int limit, `start` and `add` go over it also.  I looked into keeping all those values low(using %67) but I couldn't find a way to do it in less than 4 characters( the cost of __int64 over just int).

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 113 bytes

```
l,c=(1..100).step(2).to_a,0
[c+=l.count{|i|i%67<1},l=l.zip(l[1..-1]).map{|x,y|x+y if y}.compact!]until[]==l
p c
```

Comment: `until[]==l` instead of `while !l.empty?` saves 5 characters

Answer (score 1):

## Q, <strike>53</strike> 43

```
sum 0=(raze{1_msum[2]x}\[1+2*(!)50])mod 67
```

.

```
q)sum 0=(raze{1_msum[2]x}\[1+2*(!)50])mod 67
17i
```

Don't have to cast to long in q 3.0 which saved some characters.

Answer (score 0):

#### scala, 125 chars:

```
def s(v:Seq[Long]):Seq[Long]=if(v.size==1)v else 
v++s(v.sliding(2).map(v=>v(0)+v(1)).toSeq)
s(1L to 99 by 2).count(_%67==0)
```

Since the first row contains the number 67, which is divisible by 67, and the next number, divisible by 67 is 2*67 is bigger than 99, we know that we start with count = 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl (84+1)

there might still be a way to shorten this :)

```
@q=grep$_%2,1..99;while(@q){$_%67or$c++for@q;$q[$_]+=$q[$_+1]for 0..$#q;pop@q}say$c
```

Answer (score 0):

#### GolfScript, <strike>39</strike> 38 characters

```
100,{2%},0\{.{67%!},,@+\(\{.@+}%\;.}do
```